# Heroku 403 Forbidden - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, bash, laravel-5, heroku

I have a Laravel 5.8 site

https://boss-security-2.herokuapp.com/

I deployed to Heorku to test with this script that I created

```
appName='boss-security-2'
echo 'appName =' $appName


# heroku apps
# heroku apps:destroy appName --confirm appName
# ----------------------

echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile
git init
git status
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit"

heroku create $appName
heroku git:remote -a $appName
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
heroku config:set APP_KEY=9O7AegDFJhVC16jLfNNepT7TEQ7FyFZc

git push heroku master

heroku apps:info
heroku open
echo "done"
#
```

---

I kept getting

## Forbidden

>

> You don't have permission to access this resource

---

Anything **wrong** in my script ?

---

## Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.19",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "chmod -R 777 public/"
        ]
    },

}
```

---

## Update 1

I checked the log, I saw this

> Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

---

## Update 2

I have no idea why my `composer.json` in my dyno doesn't seem to have my **latest** code. I SSHed in and check.

> `heroku ps:exec`

Is this has something to do with my `composer.lock` ?

Comment: try to add the following to the script section of your composer.json 
"post-install-cmd": [
     "php artisan clear-compiled",
     "chmod -R 775 public/"
 ]

Comment: @Sehdev I tried that and update my post to show you my composer.json.

Comment: I don't think you correctly pointed Apache at the `public` directory; when I go to https://boss-security-2.herokuapp.com/public/, I get a 500 error, but that means *something* is there.

Comment: You get 500 error ? not 403 ? How is this possible ? Can you please share screenshot ?

Comment: I used the script above all the time, and it works last night. I have no idea why it is not working right now .

Comment: How do I confirm where the document root is ? get into the box ?

Comment: i get a 403 when i visit `/`, but a 500 if i visit `/public`.

Comment: That installer runs `chmod -R 777 public/`...however, `app/index.php` or maybe `public/app/index.php` seems to be absent.

Comment: please check you have php on server, if yes check cli and web php version should be same, i was facing same problem yesterday

Comment: change the folder permissions by defining it in composer "scripts": { "post-install-cmd": [ "php artisan clear-compiled", "php artisan optimize", "chmod -R 777 app/storage" ]

Comment: I'm getting 500 in your `/public` https://imgur.com/33iMiUk -- Make sure your document root is `/public` and you have given sufficient write permissions: `chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache`

Answer (score 3):

try this to solve your problem. add this in your composer.json

```
 "post-install-cmd": [
     "php artisan clear-compiled",
     "chmod -R 777 public/"
 ]
```

Comment: `chmod -R 777 public/` is not advisable, and shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> Probably You Pushed The Directories with wrong Permissions in your
>   remote git repository

1. Goto Your local code
2. Update the Permissions
3. and push back the code
4. take a pull from the Heroku app

Answer (score 2):

I've tried http://boss-security-2.herokuapp.com/artisan and it shows the artisan sourcecode. (It should not)

I think you misconfigured the root folder.

## Update

You've said that your `composer.json` is not updated. Have you tried to commit and push all your changes?

```
git add -A && git commit -m 'update' && git push heroku master
```

Then try to SSH and list the contents

```
heroku ps:exec
```

```
pwd && ls -la && cat Procfile
```

Comment: i tried this solution but it didnt work. still showing 403 Forbidden Access

Answer (score 0):

create a file named `Procfile`(no extension, case sensitive) in the root directory of your app and write `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/` in it and commit to your repo. If you're connecting via github, ensure it's `Procfile` and not `procfile`. Then deploy again. This file will tell the heroku apache server that your root directory is in the public folder where your `index.php` file is and hence direct requests to it.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed all the steps documented to get the laravel application ready for heroku, it is quiet possible the mistake is in the Procfile:

Sometimes we easily forget to include the "web:" before the other instructions. So the Profile should be on line like this:
**web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/**

Most likely this could solve the problem